# Javascript: merge objects by key

Tags: javascript, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
var countries = [
    {id: SWE, value: 5},
    {id: DE, value:10},
    {id: SWE, anotherValue: 11},
    {id: DE, anotherValue: 15}
]
```

I want to merge array elements by id. The result should look like this:

```
countries = [
    {id: SWE, value: 5, anotherValue: 11},
    {id: DE, value:10, anotherValue:15}
]
```

Right now, I'm doing this with a **for loop and a lot of if and else**.

**Question:** is there any (more elegant) javascript inbuilt functionality to achieve this?

I've tried googling this, the problem is that I'm not sure what to Google for (I'm a javascript newby). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean an array of objects? `countries` is currently not a valid object, the objects within it do not have any keys.

Comment: Certainly there is no built in JavaScript functionality to do this. You would need a third party library

Comment: Also you have SW and SWE merging together to make SWE.  Please fix your question and we'll take a look.

Comment: What happened to the one with ID "SW" ? Or was that supposed to be "SWE"? Please explain your functionality further so that we can help you. It looks like you are finding all the same ID's ( If id: "SW" was supposed to be "SWE" ), and keeping only the largest values? I see no way to do this with built in javascript in any case. you will have to make the code yourself. This isn't a generic enough case for it to be built in.

Comment: You can do this yourself. Just iterate through the array and combine this object.

Comment: Corrected SW to SWE.

Comment: I'm already iterating through the array. I was just wondering whether there was a built in vector function of some sort that would do it with less code.

Comment: and yes, I meant array. Sorry, I'm jumping a lot between Matlab, Python and JS today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```js
function mergeById(a){
  var obj={};
  
  a.forEach(function(e){
    if(e && e.id){
      obj[e.id] = obj[e.id] || {};    
      for(var _k in e) obj[e.id][_k] = e[_k]
    }
  });       
  
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {return obj[key]});
}

var countries = [
    {id: 'SWE', value: 5},
    {id: 'DE', value:10},
    {id: 'SWE', anotherValue: 11},
    {id: 'DE', anotherValue: 15}
]
document.write(JSON.stringify(mergeById(countries)))
```

Comment: No if and else. that looks way more elegant than what I've got.